# An image with width larger than the window size initially loads as the same width as the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

What I am trying to do is center an image using this bit of jQuery. The selector for my image is " .section-header img ".

```
var image_center = function(){

    var imageWidth = $('.section-header img').width();
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var centerFix = -(imageWidth-windowWidth)/2 ;

    console.log(imageWidth, windowWidth, centerFix);

    $('.section-header img').css({'left': centerFix});


}
```

I call the function when the document is ready and when the window is resized:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    image_center();

    $(window)resize(function(){
        image_center();
    }
```

My problem is that I cannot get the function to work when the window initially loads. Looking in my console, the browser reads the image as having the same width as the browser. Once I resize the browser, the actual width of the image is read. Is there something built into Chrome that is tripping me up here? Is there an easier way to do this (without using background-image)??

Thank you,

CPR

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just centering the image? https://jsfiddle.net/enry/g87ngc22/

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to use css for this job.

```
.section-header {
     background-image: url("/path/to/image.jpg");
     background-position: center;
     background-size: contain;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: this is definately the easist way to go about it but I am using wordpress to insert an image, so this isn;t an option. thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you also want the img to resize.

Here is an example with resize and your img tag + section-header div or whatever it is:

```
.section-header{
  width: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  margin-left: auto;
  position: absolute; 
}

img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

<div class="section-header">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lj4mfqLa/

**UPDATE:**

You could also try to wrap your jquery code in:

```
$(window).load(function(){  
    //initialize after images are loaded  
});
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function(){})
```

Comment: thanks for the response. This won't work because the div I am filling is 100% width and the image is even wider. I am using overflow: hidden; to only display the section of the image that fits within the div, and the jQuery function I wrote scoots that image to be centered within the div. The main issue is that the browser won't initially recognize the full width of the image, only the width of the window....its confusing so i'm sorry if im not explaining it well

Comment: @CandyPaintedRIMS you could try the UPDATE - sorry for the short answer have to get my girlfriend of the trainstation ;P

Comment: @CandyPaintedRIMS did the window.load do the job for you or do you require further ideas? (:

Comment: No it didn't end up working. I still havent figured it out. Thanks for your helpp